# Записать id в переменную из ChoiceBox в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, hibernate

Есть таблица в MySQL с двумя колонками: ID и name.
Взаимодействие с базой данных осуществляется через Hibernate.

*Записываю в ChoiceBox значение name:*

```
private void champBox(){
       Session session = sf.openSession();
        List<ChampClass> list = (List<ChampClass>) session.createQuery("from ChampClass").list();
        Iterator<ChampClass> itr=list.iterator();  
            while(itr.hasNext()){  
                ChampClass q=itr.next();   
                champSetChoiceBox.getItems().add(q.getName());          
            }
        session.close();
        }
```

*ChampClass:*

```
    @Entity
    public class ChampClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")  
    private String name;


    public ChampClass(Integer id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ChampClass(){

    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

В ChoiceBox нужно передать список name, при этом нужно при выборе получать в переменную значение ID для записи в другую таблицу.

Предполагаю, что нужно сделать листенер, но как реализовать его - не знаю.
Такой листенер только считывает значение ChoiceBox:

```
ChangeListener<String> changeListener = new ChangeListener<String>() {

     @Override
     public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, //
            String oldValue, String newValue) {

     }
 };
 champSetChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(changeListener);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Сделай чтобы твой ChoiceBox состоял из из Элементов ChampClass, и переопредели у ChampClass to String на getName.

> ```
> ChoiceBox<ChampClass> chBox = new ChoiceBox();
> ```

```
 @Entity
    public class ChampClass {
...
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

2. И в listener ты уже сможешь брать id

> choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs,oldValue,newValue)
>   ->  {
>         System.out.println(newValue.getId());
>        System.out.println(newValue.getName()); });

Comment: Спасибо, всё так просто оказалось, а я так долго ломал голову.